# How to faster 3 consecutive for loops for positioning data into new matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I want to create new matrix `experiment2` from `experiment`. The dimension of `experiment` is 13500 * **12000**. I want to sum each 10 columns (but preserves row number) to reduce the dimension.

The first set is sum of column index `0-9, 10-19, 20-29..., 13490-13449`

The second set is sum of column index `5-14, 15-24, 25-34...,13485-13494`

And input the first set into even index, the second set into odd index of `experiment2`. The new matrix is reduced to 13500 * **2400**

I am using 3 for loops here for each set and it is extremely slow. How to make it faster here?

```
window = 10

experiment2 = np.zeros(shape=(13500,2400))
for eachrow in range(13500):
    for unit in range(1200):
        for even in range(0, (2400), 2):
            # each row, sum column 0-9, 10-19,... and input to experiment2 at even
            experiment2[eachrow, even] = sum(experiment[eachrow,:][(10*unit):((10*unit)+10)])

for eachrow in range(13500):
    for unit in range(1200):
        for odd in range(1, (2400), 2):
            # each row, sum column 5-14, 15-24,... and input to experiment2 at odd
            experiment2[eachrow, odd] = sum(experiment[eachrow,:][((10*unit)+5):((10*unit)+10+5)])
```

Comment: I don't know python, but two things spring to mind. One is that you are going over all the rows twice - you may get better caching if you simply do each row twice before moving on to the next row.
The second is that you could reduce it to one pass per row by keeping a running total. Instead of adding 0-9 and 5-14 separately, perhaps if you add 0-9 for the first result, then subtract 0-4 and add 10-14 for the second, and so on, it may improve cache locality even further.

Comment: What is that `mz`?

Comment: @poke Sorry I corrected it. It is `eachrow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about it, you have to loop over all 13500 * 12000 items at least once in order to calculate the sums. You cannot do it below that, so you should attempt to solve it in exactly 13500 * 12000 iterations. That means, you should only iterate the items in the original array, and only once.

To calculate the sums, you should then avoid using things that will iterate stuff again, so no `sum`. Instead, you could just add to the target array, since it’s initialized as zeros using `np.zeros` anyway.

```
experiment2 = np.zeros(shape=(13500,2400))
for row in range(13500):
    for col in range(12000):
        # calculate the target indexes for `experiment2`. To keep the complexity
        # linear to the original array size, this has to be done in constant time
        # using only the indexes we have
        evenIndex = (col / 10) * 2
        oddIndex = ((col + 5) / 10 ) * 2 - 1

        # add the numbers
        expirement2[row, evenIndex] += expirement[row, col]

        # only add odd if we’re past 4 though, and before 11995
        if 4 < col < 11995:
             expirement2[row, oddIndex] += expirement[row, col]
```

This will work in O(N) for N being the total size of the input array, doing only a single iteration. As explained, you cannot get below this if you want to look at all numbers.

Note that this solution leaves one odd array index untouched: `expirement[row, 2399]` since that’s the last one and would only get the column indexes `11995`, `11996`, `11997`, `11998`, and `11999`. I don’t know about your use case here, but you could fill it up with the values `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` which were also left out. You would have to handle this explicitly above though (just add an `else` case).

Comment: I think `i` at oddIndex line is `col`?

Answer (score 1):

Not a numpy expert but I will write something like this:

```
experiment2 = np.zeros(shape=(13500,2400))
xeven, yeven, xodd, yodd = 0, 10, 5, 15

for eachrow in xrange(13500):
    for unit in xrange(1200):
        sumeven = sum(experiment[eachrow,:][xeven:yeven])
        sumodd = sum(experiment[eachrow,:][xodd:yodd])

        for even in xrange(0, 2400, 2):
            experiment2[eachrow, even] = sumeven
            experiment2[eachrow, even + 1] = sumodd

        xeven += 10
        yeven += 10
        xodd += 10
        yodd += 10
```

The idea is to fill odd and even columns in the same loop. Other thing, to avoid to calculate `10*unit+...` 1200 times for nothing, I store them in `xeven, yeven, xodd, yodd` and I increment them.
Also I use `xrange` that returns an iterator *(since you use python 2.7)* in place of `range` that returns a list.

Comment: One thing here is at `for even in range ...` line, the `experiment2` is updated with same `sumeven` at all even index, and the previous is replaced with new unit round value. Feel free to edit if you like. But I really got your concept. Thanks so much.